# Jquery Selecting Previous Element After Click

Tags: jquery, html, text, parent

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="well">
  <h2>Hurry Up!</h2>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a onclick="clicked()"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a onclick="clicked()"></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above is a sample of my html syntax. What I want to achieve is when "a" tag is clicked, I want to find the text of the "h2" element.

For example, when the "a" tag is clicked, the text "Hurry Up!" of h2 should be shown in console.

I tried this but its not working:

```
function clicked(){
        var title = $(this).find('h2').text();
        console.log(title);
}
```

And also this :

```
function clicked(){
        var title = $(this).parentsUntil('.container').find('h2').text();
        console.log(title);
}
```

In console, nothing appears, only a blank line.

What I want to add is i have this same syntax many times. So the h2 text should be of the container in which it was clicked, because of which I am trying it through 'this'.

Comment: pass element like this `<a onclick="clicked(this)"></a>`, get it as an argument in the function and that variable instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function clicked(element){
        var title = $(element).closest('div').find('h2').html();
        console.log(title);
        alert(title);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="well">
  <h2>Hurry Up!</h2>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a onclick="clicked(this)" href="#">Click 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a onclick="clicked(this)" href="#"> Click 2</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but along with 'hurry up' it is also showing the 'a' element text. It should only show the h2 text i.e 'Hurry up'

Comment: @user1645734 - You must have done something different than what I provided you, as in the above snippet I provided Its showing Hurry Up! in both `console.log` and `alert`. Have you run the above snippet and checked?

Comment: Yes, i am running it directly on stackoverflow, also tried it in jsfiddle. You can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/L4nkqe14/

Comment: Thats because you have not given reference to `jquery` library in jsfidlle. I have updated your fiddle and added the `jquery` library. Please check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L4nkqe14/1/)

Comment: Well, I checked the link you gave, still it is showing the a tags text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="well">
  <h2>Hurry Up!</h2>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a onclick="clicked(this)"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a onclick="clicked(this)"></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>

function clicked(elem){
   var text = $(elem).closest('h2').text();
   // text contains Hurry Up! in it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clicked(element) {
  var title = $(element).closest('ul').prev('h2').text();
  console.log(title);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <h2>Hurry Up!</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
         <a onclick="clicked(this)">clicked</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a onclick="clicked(this)">clicked</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use `.closest()` to get the ul then use `.prev()` to get the h2

Comment: I tried your code, but along with 'hurry up' it is also showing the 'li' text. It should only show the h2 text i.e 'Hurry up'

Comment: I have checked it and every tag is closed properly. i copied the code you provided, also ran it directly from stackoverflow, it is showing the li text.

Comment: if you copy it it will be ok you can see it in demo above can you show your demo?

Comment: your fiddle isnt even running

Comment: Sorry, your code is working, I just overlooked it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you aren't looking for a modular answer you can try this:

```
 function clicked(){
    var title = $(".well h2").text();
    console.log(title);
  }
```